# Скриншот полноэкранного приложения

Tags: screenshots, qt, c++

Я занимаюсь разработкой приложения [Clipper](http://clipperapp.tk), [репозиторий на GitHub](https://github.com/falceeffect/Clipper).
В ходе тестирования работы скриншотов, было выяснено, что сделать скриншот полноэкранного приложения (к примеру игры) невозможно - вместо окна приложения на скриншот попадает рабочий стол
(с остальными открытыми окнами).
Метод получения скриншота выглядит вот так:

```
inline QPixmap grabScreen()
{
    QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    return screen->grabWindow(0);
}
```

Каким образом можно исправить положение? Желательно кросс-платформенно, но хватит и Windows-only.

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Сразу оговорюсь, что точного решения не знаю,но скорее всего придется делать платформенно-зависимое решение: вот ссылка по теме:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/878726-take-screenshot-full-screen-applications-c

Дело тут вот в чем - если приложение использует OpenGL или DirectX то отрисовка происходит в другом контексте, нежели обычное окно. Хотя окно создается (как минимум через RegisterWindow). Как альтернативу (более кросс-платформенную) можно попробовать зная WId окна с игрой создать QWidget (через QWidget::find(WId)) и сграбить его - хотя я не уверен в успехе.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, буду знать, в каком направлении нужно копать :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `QGuiApplication::screens()` и сделать скриншоты всех окон, которые вернет эта функция. Возможно, на одном из них будет то, что нужно. Если это так, то можно попробовать по свойствам QScreen определить, какой из экранов видит пользователь.